# pyrcc_main.py: File does not exist 'resources.qrc'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt

I am trying to install Python plugins (to develop QT/Python plugins for QGIS).
I see the following error when I try to run the command:

Compile.bat:

```
@echo off
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo on
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

Commands:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>Compile.bat

C:\OSGeo4W64\bin>pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
C:\OSGEO4~1\...PyQt5\pyrcc_main.py: File does not exist 'resources.qrc'
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this problem and here is how I solved it...

Do a search for 'resources.qrc'.  I found it in the plugin that I had just created with QGIS plugin builder.  Then, make sure to edit the batch file described above to point to the absolute path of resources.qrc.  This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening "OSGeo4W Shell", Open the plugin folder, in that open local cmd or powershell window (Shift+Right click and then click on local cmd or powershell) and then run all those commands in that window. It worked for me. Also while pasting those commands change the QGIS version .... if your version is QGIS 3.12.3, then use these commands

```
@echo off 

call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\bin\o4w_env.bat"
 
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\bin\qt5_env.bat" 

call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.12\bin\py3_env.bat" 

@echo on 

pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```